# How to use PHP to load html into a <div> when a button is clicked

Tags: php, xhtml

I currently have a site that uses an iframe to load html into the center of the page while keeping the title and the menu static.

Is there a way to do this with PHP or should i just reuse the code for the title in every page on the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^(.*html)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<?
if (empty($_GET['page'])) $_GET['page']="index.html";
$PAGE = basename($_GET['page']);
if (!is_readable($PAGE)) {
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  $PAGE = "404.html";
}
include("template.html");
?>
```

template.html

```
<html>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td width=200>
    <a href = "/">Main</a><br>
    <a href = "photo.html">Photos</a><br>
  </td>
  <td width=600>
<? include $PAGE ?>  
  </td>
 </tr>
<table>
</html>
```

404.html

```
Sorry, page not found
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply, can you explain what the code in index.php does?

Comment: it just reuse the code for the title in every page on the site